# How do I read data over IP by using pyshark in python?

Tags: python, packet-sniffers, pyshark, data-capture

I am using the livecapture method to capture data, which is showing zero packet capture even when I am sending/receiving a file.

I am using this code to capture data by using live capture:

[image]

This is the output which I get after running the code:

[image]

Comment: Please put your code and error message into your question, do not link to images.